# Does Beacon of Hope benefit Vampiric Touch's healing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing

*Beacon of Hope* says:

> ... Choose any number of creatures within range. For
>   the duration, each target has advantage on Wisdom
>   saving throws and death saving throws, and regains
>   the maximum number of hit points possible from *any healing*.

And then *Vampiric Touch* says:

> ... On a hit, the target takes 3d6 necrotic damage, and you
>   regain hit points equal to half the amount of necrotic damage dealt.

**Emphasis mine.**

If Al casts Beacon of Hope, and targets Bob, and then Bob casts Vampiric Touch, is the healing maximized as if he had dealt maximum damage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.**

It's true that the maximum number of hit points you could possibly heal from *Vampiric Touch* in the abstract is 9 - but the healing value of the spell when cast is dependent on the damage dealt. For any specific casting of *Vampiric Touch*, the maximum (and only) healing possible is half the dealt damage, which is determined separately.