# What is the interaction between Gift of the Ever-living Ones and Dhampir Vampiric Bite ability

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, racial-traits

[The Dhampir Trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/lineages#Dhampir)  (P17 of VRGTR) Says:

> Your fanged bite....add your Constitution modifier....deals 1d4 Piercing damage.....
> You regain hit points equal to the piercing damage dealt by the bite.

The Eldritch Invocation [Gift of the Ever-living Ones](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/subclasses#EldritchInvocations) (P57 XGTE) Says:

> Whenever you regain hit points while your familiar is within a 100 feet of you, treat any dice rolled to determine the hit points you regain as having rolled their maximum value for you.

My question is:  How does this affect the damage dice inflicted by the bite?   Are they maximized?  Or is the damage rolled and then the maximum possible roll  is then taken for healing?

Comment: Related (does it happen to answer your question?): "[Does Beacon of Hope benefit Vampiric Touch's healing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103102)"

Comment: Another recent Q&A about the same kind of damage & heal effect with the same rules phrasing: [Does Gift of the Ever-Living Ones maximize the damage and/or healing from Gloves of Soul Catching?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/201809)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There seems to be some dispute over weather the ability applies. I think it does, at least RAW.

> "treat **any dice** rolled to determine the hit points".

and this:

> "You regain hit points equal to the piercing damage dealt by the bite."

What this literally says is **any dice** that were rolled in the gain of HP are maxed out. The word "equal to" while indicating no healing roll was directly involved in the HP gain, is irrelevant, because of the first statement of "any dice rolled to **determine** the hit points" Still applies. The HP could not exist without the bite dice roll.

The bite dice determined the HP; Therefor, Gift of the Ever-living Ones applies.

Comment: Key phrases is 'to determine hit points' rather than 'any dice' because the damage dice are not rolled to determine hit points, they are rolled to determine damage, and the hit points is a preset amount. HP = x, where x = damage rolled. Separate equations.

Comment: It does not matter because the healing amount was still determined by the damage dice roll.  I get that it's once removed but the language does not specify that it Cannot be.  The question is :  how was the amount of hp regained determined?  The answer is: it was determined by the bite dice roll.

Comment: As an editorial comment, the lack of thinking through these interactions before publishing shows us yet another reason that PCs as undead is a bad idea, or at least one badly implemented. (My own feedback to WoTC on the UA before Ravenloft was published was scathing in detail). VtM implemented PC vampires as the central feature of the game; this is a new coat of cheap paint on a different game ...

Answer (score 17):

#### The healing isn't rolled, so Gift of the Ever-living Ones has no effect.

Gift of the Ever-living Ones affects your healing rolls, not your damage rolls. In the case of the Dhampir trait, you roll damage, and then heal an amount equal to the amount rolled - the healing itself isn't rolled, it's simply set equal to the amount rolled by another dice roll. As a result, Gift of the Ever-living Ones has no effect, since the healing itself isn't rolled for.

If, on the other hand, you had some sort of effect that heals you and then does damage based upon the amount rolled for the healing, then you would deal maximum damage with that effect, since the healing would be maximized as well. I don't know if any such effects currently exist in the official content for the game, though.

Comment: @SamLacrumb Yup, and when you're using the Dhampir ability (or a spell like Vampiric Touch), you're not rolling dice to determine how much HP you regain - you're rolling dice to determine how much damage you do, and the HP you regain is set to a fixed value with no dice rolled (though that value happens to be determined by the damage roll).

Comment: @SamLacrumb Nope. Damage dice are damage dice, and are unaffected by Gift of the Ever-Living Ones - the healing is a fixed value. No dice are rolled for it. If they did, they'd say something like "Roll XdY dice to determine how much damage you do, then roll XdY dice to determine how much HP you heal."

Comment: Even if they weren't separate, the ability could have been phrased as "you heal for 1d4.  The victim takes that amount of piercing damage."  Then it would be a healing roll triggered by a hit, with the damage being tied to it, and Beacon of Hope or Gift of the Ever-living Ones would maximize it.